# How would I determine the row that a LinkButton was clicked on inside of a ListView in ASP.Net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, linkbutton

Say for example that I have a ListView with some columns and an extra column for a LinkButton, and that LinkButton would exist on every row in the ListView.

Is there any way to check if the LinkButton was clicked, and on which row in the ListView it was clicked on?

I'm trying to do this on my aspx.cs page instead of using a DataSource object on
the aspx page.

Edit: Here is the code for my aspx.cs page

```
protected void ServicesListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int idValue;


            var backend = new ServicesBackend();

            switch (e.CommandName)
            {
                case "View":
                    idValue = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);


                        var info = backend.GetOneService(idValue);

                        DescriptionTextBox.Text = info.Description;
                        HoursTextBox.Text = info.JobHours.ToString();
                        CommentsTextBox.Text = info.Comments;

                        DisplayServicePanel.Visible = true;
                    break;
            }
    }
```

Unfortunately the id returns 0 every time

Here is a snippet from my aspx page

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ViewButton" CommandName="View" CommandArgument='<%# Item.ServiceId %>' runat="server" OnClick="ViewButton_Click" CssClass="btn btn-default" style="display: inline-block;">View</asp:LinkButton>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually you would use a ListView with some sort of dynamic data and bind the LinkButton CommandName/CommandArgument so that on the OnItemCommand event handler, you will "know" what row/value you are firing the event for. Are you using static data or something?

Comment: Yeah, I was using a switch statement to get the specific CommandName for the button, and did a TryParse for the CommandArgument, but the id from one of my other columns which I was trying to pass into another method call, returned 0.

Comment: I'd be able to help more if I could see the problematic code

Comment: Alright, I've added in the code, and even changed up a couple of things before posting it. I tried a different approach instead of getting the row of the clicked button, but unfortunately my id value is still returning 0, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Okay, so silly mistake on my part. I forgot to set the value of the id in my back end. So I did that, and it works perfectly! Thank you Derek!

Answer (score 0):

Please set specific class name for the LinkButton then write some jquery/javascript code which will trigger when someone click that specific class like below example.

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td><a href="#" class="fa fa-fw fa-pie-chart linkbutton" data-row='1'></a></td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td><a href="#" class="fa fa-fw fa-pie-chart linkbutton" data-row='2'></a></td>
</tr>

 $(document).on('click','.linkbutton', function(){
 // you can get specific row data. all you need to do is to add this data to a custom 
 //data attribute and get data using jquery. 
  var rowData = $(this).attr('data-row');
  alert(rowData);
 console.log(rowData);
  });
```

you can also check https://jsfiddle.net/5jun3aLs/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Item Index easily by using the NamingContainer.

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //cast the sender back to a linkbutton
    LinkButton lb = sender as LinkButton;

    //get the current listview item from the linkbutton namingcontainer
    ListViewDataItem lvdi = lb.NamingContainer as ListViewDataItem;

    //get the item index from the listviewdataitem
    int index = lvdi.DataItemIndex;
}
```

aspx

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```